# Showing a quotient group as a direct sum of Cyclic groups

Tags: matrices, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let M be the matrix:
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
2& 2& 0& 4\\
0& 1& 3& 5\\
2& 5& 3& 1\\
3& 1& 7& 3\end{bmatrix}
$$
And H be the sub group of $\mathbb {Z}^4$ created by the matrix' columns.

I need to display $\mathbb{Z}^4/H$ as a direct sum of cylic groups.

How can I do that ?

(I'm sorry but I don't know how to use the math formulas)

Comment: I'm not very good at algebra, but hope I used the right symbols.

Comment: That's not the right symbols :( It's not the Z4 you wrote, it's Z^4

Comment: The discussion in http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/CHAP10%20Finitely-Generated%20Abelian%20Groups.pdf should show you what to do.

Comment: Ok, Z^4 is on the way in the review queue.

Comment: @JazzyMatrix this is not true. A similar example is $2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$ but $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is non-trivial. In this case you can column reduce the matrix (swapping columns and subtracting multiples of one column from another only) to obtain a diagonal matrix. This gives a more natural basis for $H$ so you can easily calculate the quotient

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Thanks for the correction -- deleted my comment

Comment: So, have you had a look at those notes, MathEnthusiast?

Comment: I have looked and I was able to get the matrix to the form:

1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 
0 0 2 0
0 0 0 192

Does that mean that Z^4/H is isomorphic to Z2 + Z192 ?
Or is H isomorphic to Z2 + Z192 ?

Comment: The matrix should be 

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 2& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 192\end{bmatrix}
$$